# How to update a column based on another column's value with a native query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have the following table:

| name | UpdatedName |
| --- | --- |
| toto |  |
| foo |  |

I want to run a native query that will, for each name, compute an `UpdateName` thanks to a Java method.

The reason why I want this to be a native query is because I want to make my code generic, able to perform this transformation on *any* table with *any* input and output columns. Thus, this bit of code has no idea of the entities that it is modifying. Of course, if a way to keep this generic and use something else than native queries exist, I'm interested too :)

How can I have a query which will, in essence, do this:

```sql
UPDATE table SET UpdatedName = myJavaMethod(name)
```

I know I can use native queries to do something similar to

```java
UPDATE table SET UpdatedName = :myNewValue
```

but how could I retrieve the `name` value from that row, so that I can pass `myJavaMethod(name)` as the arg?

Comment: While there are *some* databases that allow you to execute Java functions (like H2), most won't. So you either have to rewrite the Java logic as SQL, or update the rows one by one.

Comment: Oracle allows Java code store procedures too.

Comment: As well Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: PostgreSQL using PL/Java extension.

Comment: Thanks for the information on this. Is there any way to do this row by row without knowing the underlying data structure? (Like extracting the row to a Map or something similar)

Comment: I think it would be best to use a DB trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible via @Query but can be  done via EntityManager.

```
class Test {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public <T> void update(String UpdatedName, T name) {
        var data =  myJavaMethod(name);
        em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE table SET" + UpdatedName + "= '" + data.toString() + "'");
    }
}
```

I haven't tried this code but probably this would work if I have understood your requirement correctly.

Comment: Where does the value for name come from in your method?

Comment: I have edited to generic or you can use Object instead of generic

Comment: But the value of name comes from the query itself... I don't think this answer works